Does adjusting the speed of an animation effectively change its frames?
Animations are made up of frames, for example in the below animation it takes Ryu 3 frames to execute his kick, it does damage during the next 12 frames, and finally takes him 17 frames to recover.

If I need to make the animation startup take twice as long I can edit it in an animation tool and extend the animation startup to 6 frames.
However my question is, if I don't have an animation tool to do this is it a viable solution to simply adjust the speed of the animation? For example, if I want the above animation to have a startup of 6 frames instead of 3 would adjusting its animation speed to 0.5 achieve this or is there more to it? I understand this would also change the rest of the animation, which I am fine with.

How do you have the animation currently if you are able to extend the duration?

I'm not able to extend the duration, I can only change the animation speed inside Unity

That doesnt really answer how you currently have the animation in your project. Unity has its own animation tools, depending what you have you might be able to just double the first three frames without touching the rest.

The animations are just fbx files like most standard characters, if that's what you're asking?

Wouldn't it be more practical to repeat some frames to make the movements slower when returning the leg?

Yes you could but that would require editing the frames by hand, and in some cases it could make the animation look choppy

Simply slowing the frame rate will make the frame transitions more obvious. "Interpolating" extra frames would keep things smooth (such as it was).
